# Publish apk with preloaded contentProvider

Tags: android, apk, android-contentprovider, google-search, android-app-indexing

Is it possible to pre-populate my ContentProvider before I publish my apk? My ContentProvider is backed by an sql db.

**reason (for the curious):**

Google is complaining about indexing my app because of blocked content. The blocked content would be solved if data was already loaded. A possible solution would be to pre-load the contentProvider and then package the apk.

Comment: A `ContentProvider` cannot be "pre-loaded", because a `ContentProvider` is simply an implementation of an API. If you explain what your specific `ContentProvider` is using for a backing store (SQLite database? flat files? random numbers?), we might be able to suggest data distribution strategies for that backing store.

Comment: Well, if the content is blocked, hiding it somehow won't help since in the end it is still there.

Comment: @CommonsWare I forgot to add that. Fixed: sql db

Answer (score 0):

You can package a SQLite database in `assets/` and unpack it on first use. [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) is a nice library for helping you do this.